# MATLAB errors when using Lagrange Multipliers?

Tags: matlab

I have code that, when run, should correctly use Lagrange Multipliers to find the maximum/minimum of a function here:

```
clear all  
syms x y L;  
f = x^4+2*y^4;  
g = x^2+5*y^2+2*y^2-10;  
firstpart=jacobian(f,[x y])-L*jacobian(g,[x y]);  
[Lsoln,xsoln,ysoln]=solve(firstpart,x^2+5*y^2+2*y^2-10);  
subs(f,{x,y},{xsoln,ysoln})  
% The coordinates that correspond with the greatest and smallest values  
% above are the maximum and minimum, respectively.
```

However, when I run it, I get four errors:

> Error using sym.getEqnsVars>checkVariables (line 92) The second
>   argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.
>
> Error in sym.getEqnsVars (line 62)
>       checkVariables(vars);
>
> Error in solve>getEqns (line 450) [eqns, vars] =
>   sym.getEqnsVars(argv{:});
>
> Error in solve (line 225) [eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing two equations as individual arguments zu solve, that is not possible. You have to put both into an array

```
 [Lsoln,xsoln,ysoln]=solve([firstpart,x^2+5*y^2+2*y^2-10] );
```